# Custom histogram metrics not showing up in prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus

I am trying to add a merics in my plain java class in a spring app, like explained [here](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#histogram)

```
static final Histogram requestLatency = Histogram.build()
        .name("my_custom_service_method_latency_seconds")
        .help("Request latency in seconds for my_custom_service

.").register();
```

...and then in method:

```
Histogram.Timer requestTimer = requestLatency.startTimer();

try{
....

}finally{
    requestTimer.observeDuration();
}
```

But on prometheus dashboard I see no such metrics.

Am I missing something here?

Edit: In application.properties, I have:

```
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Comment: Have you figure out the reason @Mandroid ? I have the same issue :/

Comment: No, I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Issue for me was using the default `.register()` method which is using the `defaultRegisty`:

```
public C register() {
  return register(CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry);
}
```

Here is the code that worked for me (after injection of `CollectorReqistry`):

```
              Histogram.build()
                  .name("requests_latency")
                  .help("Request latency in seconds.")
                  .buckets(0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3)
                  .labelNames("my label")
                  .register(collectorRegistry);
```